# Finding if one Array [(String,Bool)] contains any strings from Array2[String] in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var fakeArray [("Potato", True),("root", false),("dog", False),("cat", True)]
var OtherFakeArray ["person","cat","dog","figg"]
var finalArrat[(String,Bool)]
```

I want to find any item in first array that is in second array, append it to the final, both string and bool, and then copy the rest of the items that were not found in FakeArray and also append them to finalArray while applying FALSE bool to each so they can be stored in final array, so the result should be

```
finalArray[("dog",false),("cat",True),("figg", False),("person",False)]
```

So the final array includes all entries from otherFakeArray , the ones that could be matched with fakeArray have their original bool states, while the ones that were not found get a new False state to be added to the final one.

Comment: Why in the result the tuple with "figg" is before the tuple with "person" which are both not found with a `true` value in `fakeArray` but where in the other order in `OtherFakeArray`.

Comment: What if "cat" occurs twice in the first array (perhaps with different boolean values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out all the contents from the fakerArray that are contained in otherFakerArray. Find out all the items that are not contained and make (_, false) tuple from it and append to the ones that are contained.

Something like this,

```
var result = fakeArray.filter { OtherFakeArray.contains($0.0) }

let notFoundItems = OtherFakeArray.filter { item in
                                            !result.contains(where: { $0.0 == item })
                                    }.map { ($0, false) }

result += notFoundItems

print(result)
```

And here is bit better version,

```
let result = OtherFakeArray.map { string  in
    fakeArray.first(where: { $0.0 == string}) ?? (string, false)
}
```

**Your code review**

You are not using the Swift boolean type. It should be one of `true` or `false` and cannot be `True` and `False`. Didnt you try to compile it with xcode. It should not have compiled. How did you come up with the question without actually trying anything.

Here is how your actual type should look.

```
let fakeArray = [("Potato", true),("root", false),("dog", false),("cat", true)]
let OtherFakeArray = ["person","cat","dog","figg"]
```

Comment: Using a `flapMap()` might be a quicker way than using a `filter()` + `map()`, no? That should iterate the list OtherFakeArray.count times, instead of OtherFakeArray.count times + filteredOtherFakeArray.count times.

Comment: Dont you still have to do the comparison inside flatMap, if the fakerArray contains any element from otherFakerArray?

Comment: @Larme If you mean "quicker" in terms of runtime, then not necessarily. Returning a value from flapmap requires allocating an array, which can take more time than it does to do an extra item per iteration

Comment: @Sandeep wow it actually worked! may i ask you explain to me the logic ? i dont understand how it works, even tho it does what i need it to

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let res1 =  fakeArray.filter { otherFakeArray.contains($0.0) }
let tem = fakeArray.map { $0.0 }
let final =  otherFakeArray.filter { !tem.contains($0)}.map { ($0,false)} + res1
```